# Какой есть адекватный бесплатный компонент для импорта товаров из XML?

Tags: opencart

Стоит вопрос осуществлять импорт товаров на сайт на OpenCart из XML-файла поставщика. Есть ли опробованый бесплатный адекватный компонент для этого?

Comment: Использую anyXML, пока проблем не возникало :-)

Comment: @Nilsan так он же платный

Comment: оу виноват.... :-( ну в любом случае нормального мало вероятного чего-то найти... Я похожим образом его нашел, искал чего бесплатного и знакомый скинул его (я не знал что нулл)...

Answer (score 0):

Бесплатного универсального решения я не видел. Но сам использую [ImportYML](https://github.com/gepo/opencart-importyml). Код понятен и легко модифицируется, работает и на 1.5 и на 2 версии opencart. Если необходим импорт от разных поставщиков, с разной структурой файлов, то делаю клон модуля.